# Display page number on custom page title function

Tags: functions, customization, pagination, title

When paginating a blog archive, pages 2+ of a post archive are currently just displaying the `single_post_title` and not also the page number in the `<title>` tag.

Is there a straightforward way to display the page number when using a custom page title function in a plugin? Using something like `get_query_var` wont work because this function is outside the loop (correct?)

My function:

```
function create_page_title() {
            if ( is_front_page() )  { 
                $page_title = bloginfo('name');
                $page_title .= print(' | Company Name'); 
            } 
            elseif ( is_home() ) {
                $page_title = single_post_title();
                $page_title .= print(' | ');
                $page_title .= print(' '); 
                $page_title .= bloginfo('name');
                $page_title .= print(' | Company Name'); 
            }
            elseif (is_page() ) { ...
            }
            return $page_title;
}
```

I know I need to put something after `$page_title = single_post_title();`, but just don't know what...

Comment: there is some related code in functions.php of  the default themeTwenty Twelve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this inside your `is_page()` conditional :

```
elseif ( is_page() ) { 
 $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
 echo $page_title . ' ' . $paged . ' of '.$wp_query->max_num_pages;
}
```

The other way to achieve the same thing. The conditional statement serves to avoid adding a 0 besides the title at the first page :

```
elseif ( is_page() ) { 
   global $paged;
    if ( $paged != 0 ) {
      $custom_title = $page_title . ' Page Number :  ' . $paged;
      echo $custom_title;
    } else {
      echo $page_title;
    }
 }
```

Comment: Use `return` instead of `echo` if you want a return.